# Problema com Loop While e Foreach(PHP & JS)

Tags: php, javascript, pdo

Eu tenho dois valores de duas colunas difetentes no database: Coluna: Laitude, Longitude.Armazenei valores dentro de cada coluna da tabela: Localização. Quero listar todos os valores da Latitude e logintude. so que para mostrar essa geolocalização, preciso usar javascript. Então criei variaveis JS para armazenar dados php dentro do javascript. so que agora não sei como fazer para criar um loop e mostrar todos os valores. Do jeito que tentei fazer só retorna uma linha da coluna: Latitude e Longintude. Quero retornar todas as linhas.

```
<?php foreach($Zone as $Zones){?>

<script>


        var ZoneLogitude  = <?=$Zones["Longitude"]?>;
        var ZoneLatitude  = <?=$Zones["Latitude"]?>;


        var marker        = L.marker([Latitude, Longitude]).addTo(mymap);
        var quarter       = L.circle([ZoneLatitude, ZoneLogitude], {

          color: 'yellow',
          fillColor: 'yellow',
          fillOpacity: 0.5,
          radius: 900
          }).addTo(mymap);

          L.tileLayer('https://tile.jawg.io/jawg-sunny/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access-token=A1r6TvsYKBMdJu6fyH3rpZKdqrb8Kv8O6iiAsLQR2GHAmyxTL1Uk1vpV5dpCURZV', {}).addTo(mymap);
        mymap.attributionControl.addAttribution("<a href=\"https://www.jawg.io\" target=\"_blank\">&copy; Jawg</a> - <a href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org\" target=\"_blank\">&copy; OpenStreetMap</a>&nbsp;contributors")
</script>
<?php }?>
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeceria!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre complicado misturar duas linguagens *server-side* e *client-side*, parto do principio de nenhuma delas deve interferir uma na outra. Deste princípio, podemos chegar neste código:

```
<script>
// Se puder usar um ajax que uma rota GET para trazer esta informação via clientSide será melhor
// var zones = $.get('zones.php'); -> deve retornar um JSON.
var zones = <?php echo json_encode($Zone); ?>

// para sintaxe de repetição 'foreach' normalmente parte do plural para singular 
// no PHP foreach($zones as $zone)
// no Javascript for(var zone in zones)
for (var zone in zones) {

  var marker = L.marker([Latitude, Longitude]).addTo(mymap);
  var quarter = L.circle([zones[zone].ZoneLatitude, zones[zone].ZoneLogitude], {
    color: "yellow",
    fillColor: "yellow",
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 900
  }).addTo(mymap);

  L.tileLayer(
    "https://tile.jawg.io/jawg-sunny/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access-token=A1r6TvsYKBMdJu6fyH3rpZKdqrb8Kv8O6iiAsLQR2GHAmyxTL1Uk1vpV5dpCURZV",
    {}
  ).addTo(mymap);

  mymap.attributionControl.addAttribution(
    '<a href="https://www.jawg.io" target="_blank">&copy; Jawg</a> - <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap</a>&nbsp;contributors'
  );

}
</script>
```

Boa sorte!

Comment: agradeço por ter respondido. eu fiz um teste jogando um console.log para ver o que ele me retorna. e sim, me retornou todos os valores no console log, mas no map ele so me retorna um. se eu tirar   var mymap         = L.map('mapid').setView([Latitude, Longitude], 14); que representa a localização atual, ele me retorna todos os valores no console, mas se eu colocar de volta so retorna um so valors  em vez dos tres valores que é o total dos valores que preciso retornar

Comment: Duas coisas podem ser feitas: 1) tente adicionar dois markes no mapa para ver a possibilidade de isso ser feito; 2) talvez o problema seja lib de mapa que está utilizando, busque na documentação um auxilio parar adicionar multiplos markers. Espero que tenha ajudado, caso precise de ajuda abra outra pergunta referente a este problema. Não se esqueça de fechar a pergunta e avaliar a resposta.